# Using file_get_html(); is returning the HTML with special chars even when i use ->plaintext

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, i have spend alot of time on this issue, i want to get a  tag from a exsternal page, so i do this:

```
$dom = file_get_html($url); 

$name = $dom->find('h1'); 
$name = $name[0]->plaintext;
```

The website displays the content of the h1 tag as: Grandon Multi-Purpose HTML Template

When i echo $name it is: Grandon Multi-Purpose HTML Template

But when i save it in MySQL it becomes:

```
Grandon Multi&#45;Purpose HTML Template
```

When i save the source of the page it also shows:

```
Grandon Multi&#45;Purpose HTML Template
```

Is there any quick way to replace those special chars with their actual values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$name = html_entity_decode($name[0]->plaintext);
```